# Using IF ELSE CONDITION inside SELECT STATEMENT in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I am a beginner in STORED PROCEDURE, So I am curious about IF ELSE Condition Inside the Select Statement, Can I Use this Condition Inside it or Not?

example: `SELECT FName from USER IF LNAME = 'SAMPLE'`.

`A man who asks is a fool for five minutes. A man who never asks is a fool for life. - Chinese Proverb`

Comment: Yes, you can. Try reading basic SQL manuals, better if the one for your particular database. For your example, its a `WHERE` clause, for control flow its an `IF`, for expressions to return a value it's a `CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have mentioned in the question goes in the `where` clause of the select statement.

Basic select statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT <COLUMN NAMES YOU WANT TO RETURN IN RESULT>
FROM <TABLE FROM WHERE THE DATA SHOULD COME>
WHERE <SOME CONDITION YOU WANT TO LIMIT DATA BY>
```

So your query becomes,

```
SELECT FName from USER WHERE LNAME = 'SAMPLE'
```

There are plenty of resources where you can start learning. MSDN would be the first place to look at basics and then you can go to advanced concepts elsewhere.

Comment: What about if I need two answers Sir if it does not meet the Condition then something else will be shown?

Comment: Then you can use case statement in the column name list. Take a look at it's syntax.

Comment: You're a Legend Sir. Thanks.